# Is it possible to invert the trackpad orientation for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, touchpad

I'm running a MBP with OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard and recently got an external (Magic) Trackpad. I don't like the angle of the trackpad and want to flip it around so that the battery bar is on the side facing me.

I found [this article](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20101029060726179) mentioning it might be possible to invert the 
Magic Trackpad orientation with these commands:

```
defaults write com.apple.trackpad.orientation TrackpadOrientationMode 1
```

or

```
sudo defaults write com.apple.MultitouchSupport ForceAutoOrientation YES
```

I've tried using them and rebooting, but it does not seem to have any effect.

Is it possible to invert the trackpad orientation for Mac OS X?

Comment: Can confirm `ForceAutoOrientation` works in Yosemite 10.10.3. A reboot of the trackpad, not OS X, does the trick. Also confirmed here: http://blog.pythonaro.com/2015/01/how-to-invert-apple-magic-trackpad.html

Comment: Do you have anything working for OSX 10.15 (Catalina)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These should work on OS X 10.6, the key here is resetting the orientation:

> With this hidden pref, the trackpad auto-detects hand orientation from 5 resting fingers and rotates the coordinate system to match.

So after setting these and rebooting, rest five fingers on the bottom of the track pad so that it will auto-orientate.

Answer (score 3):

I know, it's a two-year bump, but I saw this question after responding to the identical but newer https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/121499/reverse-magic-trackpad-turn-180%C2%B0… thought I'd keep this one current too.

```
sudo defaults write com.apple.MultitouchSupport ForceAutoOrientation YES
```

still works on Mavericks 10.9.5 (requires an admin pw and a reboot). I haven't personally tried `defaults write com.apple.trackpad.orientation TrackpadOrientationMode 1` but that may still work too.

Answer (score 2):

This appears not to work anymore on MacOS 10.12 (Sierra). Corroboration from Apple discussion forum, here: https://discussions.apple.com/message/30704137#message30704137

Comment: A piece of software called [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net/) makes this possible in Sierra, as described [here](http://blog.pythonaro.com/2015/01/how-to-invert-apple-magic-trackpad.html).

Answer (score 1):

Just open terminal and type:

```
sudo defaults write com.apple.MultitouchSupport ForceAutoOrientation YES

sudo defaults write com.apple.trackpad.orientation TrackpadOrientationMode 1
```

No need to reboot, just disable and enable bluetooth and it will work...

Just applied it on 10.10.2 and now 10.11.3.